# Makefile with packrat package

Tags: r, makefile, packrat

I am using the `packrat` package for my project the first time, and I want to use a Makefile to run specific scripts in a specific order for different targets. However. I organized my file like this:

- `main_dir/packrat/`
- `main_dir/subproject1/R_scripts_1/Makefile`

When I run `R CMD BATCH someRfile.R` from within the Makefile, R is not using the packrat libs, but the default user libs, which is not what I want. 
Is there any way to force all R processes startet in any subdir of the packrat dir, to use only the packrat libs?!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have to include `source("packrat/init.R")` at the very start of `someRfile.R` as in your `.Rprofile` file in your project folder.

I assume that you use R studio in the above comment.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but this does not work for me. I tried to figure out how packrat change the default libs ... it seems not to happen in `init.R`.

Comment: I see your point. Then I guess the best option is to use the `.libPaths` function at the start of `someRfile.R` to set the library paths to the sub directories of the `packrat` directory.

Comment: Hi. I know I can do this with `.libPaths()` but I thought there would be a smoother way to do that, because I have a lot of files (ok I could make a separate `.Renviron`for each folder.) and a lot of subproject folders. :-(

Answer (score 1):

Just had this issue - the following fixed it.

Add an `.Rprofile` to each subdirectory (and sub-subdirectory etc.) containing the following,

```
source("../.Rprofile", chdir = TRUE)
```

From the packrat [docs](https://rstudio.github.io/packrat/limitations.html)